# I am trying to generate a pdf and download it using asp.net. its not working fine in firefox browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, firefox, download

Here is the code snippet I am using for generating and downloading a PDF.
I am using Nreco PDF generator.

```
pdfBytes = (new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter()).GeneratePdf(html, generalInventory + closingDiv);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
                Response.Buffer = true;
                ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.End();
```

This is working fine in Chrome browser, but in Firefox it doesn't get downloaded with a PDF extension.

What could be the reason for this issue?

--

Comment: Q: What exactly "isn't working"???  Q: Do the IIS logs show anything?  Have you looked in Firebug (browser-side debugging for older versions of FF)?  Have you tried stepping through the server-side code in MSVS?

Comment: @paulsm4 
Pdf is downloaded but not in pdf extension. Its getting downloaded in windows file format. I can't check the IIS logs as I dont have the access to them. gone through Visual studio by debugging didn't find any exception.

Comment: Step through the MSVS debugger and see what "filename" is set to.  This line determines what file name (including file suffix) the browser will default to for "Save as": `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);`.  Also check the NReco documentation: https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx

Comment: "windows file format". Which file format? There's no such as thing as "windows" format. And changing the extension doesn't change the format of the contents. It's still a PDF, you can still open it with a PDF viewer if you want to. Does the filename have space is in it, by any chance? Try `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename='" + fileName + "'");`

Comment: Thank you everyone.
@ADyson I have gone through the file name, yeah it got space init.

Comment: @RaagiShiva Great. I have added as the answer, if you are able to accept it - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the filename have any spaces in it, by any chance?

Change your code to

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename='" + fileName + "'");
```

(adding single quotes round the filename) to cover this possibility. Firefox in particular is known to have problems with this.